# Conforming to Identifiable in Objective-C

Tags: swift, objective-c, interop

I want to make the existing Objective-C classes conforming to [`Identifiable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable) protocol so that I could use them as list item in `SwiftUI`.

```objectivec
@interface MyClass: NSObject // What to do?
@end
```

For some reason, Googling doesn't help at all. Is it possible?
If not, is there a good alternative that doesn't require me to keep creating wrapper classes?

```swift
class MyClassWrapper: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var myClass: MyClass
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an `extension` to conform to `Identifiable` in Swift -- then just specify which property should be used as the `id`:

```objc
//obj-c
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* myIdProperty;
@end
```

```swift
//Swift
extension MyClass : Identifiable {
    public var id: String {
        myIdProperty
    }
}
```

I used `NSString/String` here, but you could use `NSUUID/UUID` or any other `Hashable`-conforming `id` type.

Comment: Just discovered that Xcode 12.5 is happy if I named the property `id` (even though it is supposedly a keyword) like `@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *id;` and then I can simply do `extension MyClass : Identifiable {}`.

Comment: Nice — very convenient

Comment: Nice thinking there!